# Porque al consultar getElementById solo, y un getElementById con una especificacion, no es el mimso resultado

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este codigo:
 `<strong>Total</strong>: <span id="stotal"></span>`
el valor de "stotal" se da a traves de un codigo jquery, que actualmente esta funcionando y me muestra el numero correcto como se puede ver en la imagen [image: imagen]

Al consultar con el codigo js dentro del html:
 `console.log(document.getElementById("stotal"));`
Me muestra en la consola la etiqueta correctamente con sus valores correctos, por ejemplo la propiedad **innerHTML: "$ 3000"**

Pero al consultar con
`console.log(document.getElementById("stotal").innerHTML);`
Me muestra en la consola **empty string**

Entonces no entiendo por que no coincide...

EDIT:

Este es e codigo JS mencionado

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.Shop = function( element ) {
        this.$element = $( element );
        this.init();
    };
    
    $.Shop.prototype = {
        init: function() {
              this.$subTotal = this.$element.find( "#stotal" );
...
//Dentro de un public method
   var total = this.storage.getItem( this.total );
   this.$subTotal[0].innerHTML = this.currency + " " + total;
```

Comment: A mi en ambos casos me da bien. Compruebalo aquí: https://jsfiddle.net/x5zncuoy/

Comment: Efectivamente funciona, pero no se por qué a mi no...

Comment: Pues pega tu código entero en el editor de la pregunta y así veremos que le ocurre... a ciegas va a ser dificil ayudarte

Comment: ¿Qué es `$element`?

Comment: Es un codigo JS de 700 lineas...

Comment: `(function( $ ) {
 $.Shop = function( element ) {
  this.$element = $( element );
  this.init();
 };`

Comment: Es por como funciona javascript y `getElementById`, puse una respuesta con ejemplo sencillo de cómo replicar "el problema"

Answer (score 0):

Si lees [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) sabrás lo que hace `getElementById()`:

> Devuelve una referencia al elemento por su ID.

Es decir, que en el primer caso obtienes la referencia al elemento, y en el segundo caso obtienes una propiedad en específico del elemento que es su contenido HTML.

```js
/*Esto muestra el elemento en sí mismo*/
console.log(document.getElementById("stotal"));

/*Esto muestra una propiedad del elemento (innerHTML)*/
console.log(document.getElementById("stotal").innerHTML);

/*Esto muestra OTRA propiedad del elemento (su id)*/

console.log(document.getElementById("stotal").id);
```

```html
<strong>Total</strong>: <span id="stotal">$ 3000</span>
```

Podríamos decir que `getElementById()` se suele usar como una buena práctica, para obtener una sola vez la referencia a los elementos, y a partir de ahí, usamos esa referencia si queremos obtener algo de ese elemento o modificar algo de él.

Por ejemplo:

```js
var mSpan = document.getElementById("stotal");
var inputMonto = document.getElementById('monto');

console.log(`Valor del input antes de cambiarlo: ${inputMonto.value}`);

/*Cambiamos el value del input*/
inputMonto.value = mSpan.innerHTML;

console.log(`Valor del input después de cambiarlo: ${inputMonto.value}`);

console.log(`Contenido del span: ${mSpan.innerHTML}`);
console.log(`Id del span: ${mSpan.id}`);

/*Cambiamos el contenido del span*/
mSpan.textContent = "$ 7000";
console.log(`Nuevo contenido del span: ${mSpan.innerHTML}`);
```

```html
<strong>Total</strong>: <span id="stotal">$ 3000</span>

<input type='hidden' name='monto' id="monto" value='XXXXX' />
```

Si observas, se crea en `mSpan` una referencia al elemento, y luego se usa `mSpan` cada vez que se quiere trabajar con ese elemento.

Comment: Eso lo entiendo, lo que no entiendo es poque al intentar especificar una propiedad del elemento, me da un empty string

Comment: @mrblackxz revisa el última fragmento de código, verás que el `value` del `input` se actualiza sin ningún problema.

Comment: Efectivamente es así, pero como se dijo en otra respuesta, mi html se actualiza ya que viene de un jquery, por lo tanto al hacer referencia al elemento, se obtiene antes de esa actualización y ese es el problema

Comment: @mrblackxz en ese caso simplemente tienes que acoplar tu código, para obtener los elementos en el momento adecuado, cuando tengan sus valores definitivos. Sea como sea, conviene poner siempre en las preguntas un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable donde se pueda analizar el problema de una forma global para darte una mejor solución.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es porque probablemente estás imprimiendo la referencia del objeto antes de setear el valor.

Me explico, indicas que el valor de `stotal` es obtenido a través de jquery, `document.getElementById("stotal")` es una referencia al objeto, por más que lo muestres en consola, sus atributos se actualizarán si existe algún código que los modifique, por ende, siempre que revises esa referencia, los valores serán los actuales, mientras que `document.getElementById("stotal").innerHTML` es un string, no una referencia, este valor no se actualiza en la consola, sino que muestra el dato que existía al momento de imprimir.

Poniéndolo en español, si ejecutas el siguiente código en una consola:

```js
document.getElementById("stotal").innerHTML="valor inicial";
console.log(document.getElementById("stotal"));
console.log(document.getElementById("stotal").innerHTML);
document.getElementById("stotal").innerHTML="nuevo valor";
console.log(document.getElementById("stotal").innerHTML);
```

El resultado será algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
span#total:
  ...
  innerHTML: "nuevo valor"
  ...
valor inicial
nuevo valor
```

## Actualización:

Para "mantener" la referencia inicial, el valor sin cambiar, el objeto se puede clonar:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("stotal").cloneNode(true))
```

Comment: Entiendo. Entonces como podria solucionarlo?

Comment: La consola es para hacer debug, cierto? simplemente toma en cuenta eso, imprime el valor de la propiedad que necesitas y listo, o clona el elemento `console.log(document.getElementById("stotal").cloneNode(true))`

Comment: claro, es para debug, pero si lo clono, seguiria siendo lo mismo, estaria clonando el empty string o no?

Comment: Estarías clonando el valor que tenga al momento de imprimir en consola, si ese valor era una cadena vacía, se mantendrá esa cadena vacía

Comment: entiendo, pero lo que necesito es obtener la cadena "$ 3000", no la cadena vacia

Comment: Entonces imprime el valor después de hacer: `this.$subTotal[0].innerHTML = this.currency + " " + total;`

Comment: Como se dijo anteriormente, el imprimir el valor es para debug, lo que realmente necesito es darle el valor a un "value" de un "hidden input". Pero al momento de hacer esto, me da un undefined ya que es un empty string.

Comment: `<input type='hidden' name='monto' id="monto" value='XXXXX' /> <script>document.getElementById('monto').value = document.getElementById("stotal").innerHTML);</script>`

Comment: La pregunta es "Porque al consultar getElementById solo, y un getElementById con una especificacion, no es el mimso resultado", tienes dos opciones, modificar la pregunta o crear una nueva con el problema en particular

Comment: Jajajaja ?? Amigo es un hecho, como está demostrado en la pregunta, no es el mismo resultado en mi caso, que es lo que estoy buscando solucionar

Comment: Tu último código parece incorrecto, no se si sera un typo o no.  Pones `<script>document.getElementById('monto').value = document.getElementById("stotal").innerHTML);</script>`  pero le sobra el último `)`.  A ver si va a ser eso el gran problema que tienes, un fallo tipográfico que no nos has mostrado en tu pregunta.

Comment: @mrblackxz No somos adivinos, no vemos lo que tu ves, nos gusta ayudar, pero necesitamos colaboración por parte del que pregunta.  Si es eso que acabo de comentar, la próxima vez te recomiendo que te leas detenidamente [ask] y pongas un ejemplo mínimo reproducible, porque muchos, al intentar crear los ejemplos acaban sin poner la pregunta porque por el mero hecho de tener que redactarla se dan cuenta de sus errores. [Te he votado negativamente porque solo dices que no funciona.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2871#2871)

Comment: @mrblackxz No entiendo tu reacción. ¿Te has leido mi comentario anterior? Donde te dije que te sobraba un paréntesis al final en este cacho de código:  `<script>document.getElementById('monto').value = document.getElementById("stotal").innerHTML);</script>` ... Es decir, donde pone `innerHTML);`  tendria que ser `innerHTML;` ¿era eso o no era eso? ¿con eso se soluciona tu problema?

Comment: No, no era eso…

Comment: @mrblackxz Sigues sin editar tu pregunta y sin agregar más información que pueda ayudarnos a ayudarte. Va a ser muy dificil así. Aún así, el código que has puesto en los comentarios con el `input` y el `script` solo se ejecuta al cargar la página, pues no está vinculado a ningun evento (addEventListerner o en jquery con `on(change)` por ejemplo, o un `trigger` )). Si la asignación de contenido que haces mediante jquery a `stotal` se ejecuta más tarde, que eso parece, es lógico que no te funcione.

Comment: y por lo mismo estoy buscando una solucion amigo